# jQuery setInterval showing violation warning

Tags: jquery, setinterval, amcharts

I'm using amChart.js for showing some charts. So I want to refresh the chart by setInterval. When I have add setInterval it showing infinite warning errors in console.

Warning errors are:

> amcharts.js:1 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
>
> [Violation] 'load' handler took 1223ms
>
> 50[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took ms
>   fav-1.png:1 GET http://localhost/doha-oasis/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/fav-1.png 404 (Not Found)
>
> 98[Violation] 'setInterval' handler took ms
>   amcharts.js:1 [Violation] Handling of 'mousewheel' input event was delayed for
>
> 3574 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CompleteF9();

function CompleteF9() {
    fetchdata3();

    function fetchdata3() {
        var htHum_det = jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php bloginfo('
            template_directory ')?>/ajax-wellness.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'table_name1': 'table1',
                'table_name2': 'table2',
                'table_name3': 'table3',
                'table_name4': 'table4',
                'table_name5': 'table5',
                'table_name6': 'table6',
                'table_name7': 'table7',
                'table_name8': 'table8',
                'table_name9': '',
                'flag': 'eight'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                bCO2Call3(result.dataProvider);
            },
            error: function(ts) {
                alert("Error:" + ts.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(fetchdata3, 2000);
    });
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("htHum", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "black",
        "dataProvider": "",
        "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
        "zoomOutOnDataUpdate": false,
        "valueAxes": [{
            "logarithmic": true,
            "dashLength": 1,
            "gridAlpha": 0.2,
            "guides": [

                {
                    "dashLength": 6,
                    "label": "AVERAGE(65%RH)",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "inside": true,
                    "position": "right",
                    "lineColor": "#fff",
                    "lineAlpha": 1,
                    "value": 65,
                }
            ],
            position: "left"
        }],
        "gridAboveGraphs": true,
        "startDuration": 0.2,
        "graphs": [{
            "title": "Hotel Tower F5",
            "theme": "light",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value1"
        }, {
            "title": "Hotel Tower F23",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value2"
        }, {
            "title": "Hotel Tower F24",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value3"
        }, {
            "title": "Hotel Tower F25",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value4"
        }, {
            "title": "Hotel Tower F26",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value5"
        }, {
            "title": "Hotel Tower F27",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value6"
        }, {
            "title": "Hotel Tower TF1",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value7"
        }, {
            "title": "Hotel Tower TF2",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]%RH</b>",
            "valueField": "value8"
        }],
        "chartCursor": {
            "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
            "cursorPosition": "mouse",
            "selectWithoutZooming": false,
            "oneBalloonOnly": true
        },
        "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
        "categoryField": "category",
        "categoryAxis": {
            minPeriod: "ss",
            "parseDates": true
        },
        "titles": [{
            "text": "Hotel Tower Humidity",
            "size": 15
        }],
        "legend": {
            "color": "#fff",
            "valueText": "[[value]]%RH",
            "position": "right",
            "pulled": true,
            "align": "left",
            "labelText": "[[title]]",
            "rollOverGraphAlpha": 20,
            "markerLabelGap": 20
        }
    });

    function bCO2Call3(data) {
        var dataProvider = [];
        chart.dataProvider = data;
        chart.validateData();
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm using duplicate of this same script for another charts.

Comment: A warning is not an error. But `async: false` is (at least) suspicious.

Comment: I changed the `async: false`, but no use. The warning is in infinite loop. So the graph chart is very slow.

Comment: The violations seem to be related to the mouse wheel events amcharts is listening to. Try disabling the mouse wheel handling (set [`mouseWheelScrollEnabled`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#mouseWheelScrollEnabled) and [`mouseWheelZoomEnabled`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#mouseWheelZoomEnabled) to false). If that doesn't help, how much data are you trying to render? V3 serial charts aren't optimized for a lot of data, which might explain the load violations.

Comment: I'm using only around 80 points and my data will be pulled to charts every 2 seconds (we can increase the interval time up-to  2 minutes). Also, I don't want to change the `mouseWheelZoomEnabled` feature. Still shall I update my amChart V3 to V4?

Is this the correct method to use `setInterval` in ajax. Kindly correct me if the above method is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Sarbaz - It may be only 80 points but you have 8 graphs, so that's still a significant amount of data to render in v3 (assuming each graph has data for each point, that's 640 points). Increasing the interval time might help since loading seems to take up more than half the interval time between updates. Using millisecond timetsamps instead of date strings will also speed parsing up in each update. Worst case, consider using the stock chart in v3 since it's a more efficient for date-based data and will group your data (still, use millisecond timestamps to squeeze out more performance).

Comment: @xorspark Thank you so much... I will try with stock chart.